# GeoGoogle(Java) - How to import the file?

Tags: java

I'm trying to use GeoGoogle for geocoding purposes from http://geo-google.sourceforge.net/

When I tried to use this line of code:

```
import geo.google.GeoAddressStandardizer;
GeoAddressStandardizer st = new GeoAddressStandardizer("AABBCC");
```

It says GeoAddressStandardizer and the import cannot be resolved, I also added the JAR to the build path already.

Has anyone met this issue before? Thanks

Solution: Get the geoGoogle-1.5.0.jar Instead inside https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~zl25/maven2/repo/geoGoogle/geoGoogle/1.5.0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

having a quick look through the geo-google source, this does exist as a constructor [here](http://geo-google.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/geo-google/geoGoogle/geoGoogle/src/main/java/geo/google/GeoAddressStandardizer.java?revision=108&view=markup).

```
public GeoAddressStandardizer(String apiKey)
```

So the problem has to lie in the way your application is using the jar.  Are you deploying to a web server or something like that (although I'd expect a classNotFoundException)?

If you look at the build config in your IDE, does the jar exist?  How did you add it?

Comment: Yes, I'm deploying it to a web server. In the build configuration, it does exist, I added through right clicking the project folder to set external JARs. I've also added other JARs with no problems.

Comment: Make sure that the jar is in the WEB-INF/lib folder inside your WAR or deployment folder.

Comment: Yep, it is too, this code is in the servlet, you can try adding this to a empty project, and somehow this error just happens